# What was Tauriel doing during the events of The Lord of the Rings movies?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, tolkiens-legendarium

[Yes, *The Hobbit* movies are nonsense. But how could I call myself a fantasy fan if I didn't demand my nonsense be as logical as possible?]

Tauriel is presented as a highly-skilled fighter and a combatant for the side of good. Despite this, she apparently did nothing during Sauron's war on the free peoples.

Was she somehow

> still mourning Killi, after all these decades?

Was she dead? Or is there another reason she didn't participate?

Comment: Her love of the halfling's leaf had clearly slowed her mind. She was kicking back in the Shire smoking a pipe all day.

Comment: @amaranth I once shared with her a bowl of Old Toby, and regret to say that she has not been the same since.

Comment: She was busy not existing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Unknown, but she probably went back to Mirkwood

Tauriel is [an original character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36615/31051) in the Jacksonverse, and only exists within it. No authoritative information about her fate after the Battle of Five Armies has been revealed.

However, in [a 2014 interview with Hero Complex](http://herocomplex.latimes.com/movies/evangeline-lilly-on-the-hobbit-it-changed-my-mind-about-acting/#/0)<sup>1</sup>, Tauriel's actress Evangeline Lilly gave her thoughts, for however much value you ascribe to actor opinions (italic is their emphasis, bold is mine):

> *HC: What do you think happens to [Tauriel] after the events of “Five Armies”?*
>
> EL: You know, it's going to sound very mundane, but **I think she goes back to Greenwood** — which would hopefully now *be* Greenwood; slowly but surely it would evolve out of Mirkwood and return to Greenwood — **and she goes back to work.** It sounds so boring, but ultimately, she has a job. She has a responsibility. She’s the head of the Elven Guard. She's not head of the Elven army — that is Prince Legolas and King Thranduil — but she's the head of the Elven Guard, and they protect their realm. And maybe she doesn’t go back to being head of guard, maybe she's been softened and wouldn't resume her old position, but in a way I feel like maybe she would be even more impassioned to protect what she loves, to protect her home, to protect what's important to her, but maybe she'll do it now with more compassion and a little bit of softness.

If that's the case, then Tauriel would have been busy [defending Mirkwood against the attack that happened there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80019/31051)

---

<sup>1</sup> The Entertainment/superhero division of the Los Angeles Times

Comment: Didn't Thranduil banish her?

Comment: @GreenMatt Yes, he did. However, considering the tone of their last scene together, it's not clear whether or not that still stands at the end of the film, or if it continued to stand over the next sixtyish years (after all, Legolas (is presumed to have) eventually returned to Mirkwood; why not Tauriel?)